# Using clojure.spec for a map

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I have the following map:

```
(def gigs {:gig-01 {:id :gig-01
                    :title "Macaron"
                    :artist "Baher Khairy"
                    :desc "Sweet meringue-based rhythms with smooth and sweet injections of soul"
                    :img "https://res.cloudinary.com/schae/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto/v1519552695/giggin/baher-khairy-97645.jpg"
                    :price 1000
                    :sold-out false}
           :gig-02 {:id :gig-02
                    :title "Stairs"
                    :artist "Brentr De Ranter"
                    :desc "Stairs to the highets peaks of music."
                    :img "https://res.cloudinary.com/schae/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto/v1519552695/giggin/brent-de-ranter-426248.jpg"
                    :price 2000
                    :sold-out false}})
```

I'd like to create a spec for it, but I'm not sure how to define the key e.g. ":gig-01" any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
(s/def ::gig-id
   (s/and keyword?
          (fn [x] (->> x name (re-matches #"gig-\d+")))))
```

Comment: Would the full spec then be?
`(s/def ::id string?)
(s/def ::title string?)
(s/def ::artist string?)
(s/def ::desc string?)
(s/def ::img string?)
(s/def ::price int?)
(s/def ::sold-out boolean?) (s/def ::gig (s/keys :req-un [::id ::title ::artist ::desc ::img ::price ::sold-out]))

(s/def ::gig-id
   (s/and keyword?
          (fn [x] (->> x name (re-matches #"gig-\d+")))))
          
(s/def ::gigs (s/and                                       
                 (s/map-of ::gig-id ::gig)))

(s/def ::db (s/keys :req-un [::gigs]))` 

@akond

Comment: You don't need `::db`, you can use `::gigs`, but yes, something like that.

Comment: And I feel like you've meant `(s/def ::id ::gig-id)`